# How many backups does iCloud save for iPhones?

Tags: iphone

I've noticed that after restoring or erasing an iPhone and setting it up, you're offered backups to restore from iCloud.

How many and how old are these backups.  I couldn't find any articles explaining this.
[image]

Comment: These backups seem to be for different users and phones. Which of the entries are for the same phone/AppleID?

Comment: They're for the same Apple ID, different iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

Per device, iCloud keeps the most recent backup, then 1–2 prior backups, regardless of age.